# MY SQL IF Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, select, where-clause

I have a mysql statement to retrieve values from a table called dateTable (I have date (STRING), and dayId(INT) columns in this table) where I want to retrieve value with a specific date format and if that date does not exist in the exact date format yyyy-mm-dd then search if you have date with format dd-mm else retrieve the records for the day of week of that date. the query below returns all possibilities (date with yyy-mm-dd format, and dates with mm-dd format and dates for the day of week 'which is 4 in this case')

Please note that I tried to use CASE WHEN, and it gave me the same result

```
 SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dateTable
WHERE
    dateTableId = 4
        AND IF(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2015-08-19', '%Y-%m-%d'), date=STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
        IF(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2015-08-19', '%m-%d'), date=STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d'),dayId = DAYOFWEEK('2015-08-19')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `union all`:

```
SELECT dt.*
FROM dateTable dt
WHERE dateTableId = 4 AND
       date = '2015-08-19'
UNION ALL
SELECT dt.*
FROM dateTable dt
WHERE dateTableId = 4 AND
      DAYOFWEEK(date) = DAYOFWEEK('2015-08-19') AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dateTable dt
                  WHERE dateTableId = 4 AND date = '2015-08-19'
                 );
```

I'm not sure what comparisons you are trying to make -- you are wantonly comparing dates and strings with no regard for type.  This logic is based on your description, but it can easily be tweaked.  The key is the `not exists` and `union all`.

Comment: But this is a large table in and this is a sub query, is it ok to do UNION in this case....

Comment: @Dev . . . That seems to be what your logic requires.  If you are concerned, you can post *another* question with more details about the query you are actually using.